# .NET 1.1 assembly in .NET 2.0 project: Is .NET 1.1 required?

Tags: .net, assemblies, runtime

I am upgrading project from 1.1 to 3.5.
There are some references left to .NET 1.1 assemblies.

The question is:
Do I have the requirement now to have both .NET 1.1 and 2.0 (3.5) on the deployed machine or it can be run without 1.1?

Cheers,
Dmitriy.

Comment: have you tried using the upgrade manager for your project in Visual Studio?

Comment: The project is not in Visual Studio (Borland C# Builder), so I can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referencing a specific version of the assembly (i.e. Specific Version is set to true in the properties of the references) then yes, you will need both.

If you are not referencing specific versions, then no, you will not need both, and your application should be able to use the 3.0 assemblies (although you take your chances by not testing it specifically with 3.0!)

Comment: It appears that the OP has only a single version (built on .NET 1.1) of the concerned assembly.